# Is there any research on multi-currency proof of stake?

Tags: proof-of-stake

At the end of Vitalik's 2017 blog post "Proof of Stake FAQ", he has a section on multi-currency proof of stake where he says "there has been a lot of interest" in these protocols and mentions some "designs" that have been proposed. However, after scouring the web and articles on Google Scholar, I still couldn't find much research on this topic. Does anyone know of any resources?